# View controller variations in a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've got a view controller that has two variations of subviews, based on one user choice.  If the user chooses A in a segmented control, then one set of subviews is shown, and if the user chooses B, a different set of subviews is shown.

Is there a way to layout these subviews in a storyboard - without laying the A views and B views on top of each other?

Essentially, I want to be able to show a multiple variants of view structure and hierarchy within one view controller in a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create two different View Controllers in the storyboard with two different segues. This two View Controllers should inherit from the same class so you will have just one code to deal with the two scenarios.

Just be careful to check if the views you are trying to access in your code exist before you try to use it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem with that approach is that I don't know which view controller to segue to until after the user makes their choice (A or B).  I could use three view controllers - one for the initial choice, and then one for A and one for B - but using three controllers seems clumsy for what is logically only one controller.

Comment: So let me understand it better, you have vc1 and you segue to vc2 where you have an option to view1 and view2, is not possible to add the option in vc1?